# Scala unable to add values org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to add values to `org.json.simple.JSONObject` but unable to do so.

```
val newObjt = new JSONObject
 newObjt.put("memId","2")
```

I have java code which I am trying to convert to scala, facing this issue:

> ```
> Error:(39, 19) overloaded method value put with alternatives:
>   (x$1: K,x$2: V)V <and>
>   (x$1: _1,x$2: _2)_2
>  cannot be applied to (String, String)
>           newObjt.put("memId","2")
>                   ^
> ```

Comment: See http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/4479

Comment: Yes already had a look, but unable to fix this,

Comment: @vinayak_narune have you found a solution to your question here?